# Bash syntax error when `cd`ing into directory

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, quoting

> **So, after doing a little digging, I got it to work. You do get far enough in the install using WINE for this to work properly. Here are the steps:
>
> 1. Open the shell, and type in `cd .wine`
> 2. `cd drive_c`
> 3. `cd Program\ Files\ (x86)/`
> 4. `cd NETGEAR`
> 5. `cd A6200`
> 6. `cd Drivers`
> 7. `sudo diswrapper -i nameoffile .inf`
> 8. `sudo modprobe diswrapper`
> 9. `sudo ndiswrapper -m`
>
> And that got it to work. Note: The adapter did NOT work until after the command `sudo modprobe diswrapper`
>
> – thechemEnt May 3 '14 at 22:52**

The text above is concerning a netgear wifi USB adapter I am trying to get functioning on Linux Mint 17.4.

I am using the `cd` change directory command and entering the appropriate directory he is stating in sequence (I have the exact directories available on my install) as he states it.  When I get to the `Program Files (x86)` folder I get an error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('
```

I can't, rather, I have no idea how to get to the next folder because of this error.  What is causing this?  What syntax do I need to use to get into that folder so I can dig deeper as required to get to the driver.

Comment: Sorry,  I'm using the terminal for this

Comment: We only support official releases of Ubuntu.

Comment: May we assume you are using Windows **XP** driver files? ndiswrapper won't work otherwise.

Comment: I used the drives from the link provided from the original post on askubuntu.   I don't know if they are xp drivers or something else.  I did however follow through on all the directions on that original post and I believe it still is not working.  I'm trying to remember the command to see the info for the devices.  I am so sorry everyone. I'm really green.  Been on Linux for about 3 hours.  :-)

Comment: You may get valuable clues from two commands: `ndiswrapper -l` and also: `dmesg | grep ndis`.

Comment: The error message should be a hint. There is only one `(` in your script, so obviously, `bash` is complaining there. You can guess from that, that `(` is a character with special meaning which has to be quoted, like the rest of them. Generally, it's a good practice to quote filenames just in case.

Answer (score 7):

You need to quote the directory name

```
"Program Files (x86)"
```

or

```
'Program Files (x86)'
```

or escape the spaces AND parentheses using backslashes

```
Program\ Files\ \(x86\)
```

Steps 1 to 6 can also be done in one, as you can directly go into the subdirectories with `cd`:

```
cd .wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/NETGEAR/A6200/Drivers
#or
cd .wine/drive_c/"Program Files (x86)"/NETGEAR/A6200/Drivers
```

Answer (score 3):

You can type:

```
cd
```

Then, the first character of the directory name and hit TAB key. The shell interpreter (like bash shell) will complete the path in the current directory. Hit TAB to show all options which start with the character.

```
cd "Program Files (x86)"
```

You can also change dir (cd) to other paths:

```
cd ~/
```

Then, hit TAB key to see all your home directories.